# Why is VBA running my code lines out of order?

Tags: vba, debugging, ms-word

I wrote a "simple" code to find quotations of a certain length in a Word file (which I ultimately want to format using a different sub). The parts all worked fine individually, but now the search is basically skipping strings it's supposed to find in the text and apparently running lines of code out of order.

I tried break mode and watching the value of `Selection`, and here's where it gets weird: it keeps finding the next instance of the search parameters (selects in the document and changes the value of `Selection`) as I run each line of code, including within `With Selection.Find`, before `.Execute`!

```
Sub FindQuotesTest()

Dim quotevar As String, loopvar As Boolean

Findquote:
loopvar = False 'Doesn't seem necessary, added to try debugging
Selection.Collapse 'Not sure if this is necessary
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = ChrW(8220) & "*" & ChrW(8221) 'Any amount of text between an opening and a closing curly double quotation marks.
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop 'To avoid a crash when reaching the end of the document
        End With
Selection.Find.Execute

loopvar = Selection.Find.Execute

With Selection
    .MoveStartWhile Cset:=ChrW(8220) 'Removes the opening quotation mark from selection
    .MoveEndWhile Cset:=ChrW(8221), Count:=wdBackward 'Removes the closing quotation mark from selection
End With 'I need this for the further formatting and to count the text string

quotevar = Selection.Range

If Len(quotevar) < 157 Then 'Repeats the search if the quote isn't long enough.
If loopvar = True Then GoTo Findquote 'Prevents infinite loop when reaching the end of the document by relying on wdFindstop
End If

End Sub
```

In break mode, this should find one string of text within double quotation marks at a time, and only go to the next when it reaches the `GoTo` loop, and do that until it reaches one with the designated length (should loop through `.Find` a few times).
When I run the macro again, it should find the next instance of the long quotation (it seems to be finding every second one instead. In my previous attempts, the macro would only run once and would not find the next instance when run again, which doesn't happen with this code).

The bizarre behaviour of time-travelling break mode put me off here, so I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: hi. why do you have Selection.Find.Execute and next  loopvar = Selection.Find.Execute. u are doing the find two times...

Comment: Good question, I had to add loopvar because the value of `Selection.Find.Execute` was not being kept by the time I needed it. In other words, without that the macro would not go through the loop. Why does that repeat the search though, if loopvar is Boolean?

Comment: @Luis Curado Actually that did solve the problem, I only kept `loopvar = Selection.Find.Execute` and added a direction in `Selection.Collapse wdEnd`. Thanks so much!
I thought the previous would only assign a value to a variable, not treat it as another instruction to run. Oh well, TIL.

Comment: The bizarre behaviour remains unexplained though, but I guess my main problem can be considered solved...

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "“*”"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .End - .Start > 159 Then
      With .Duplicate
        .Start = .Start + 1
        .End = .End - 1
        'Process string here
      End With
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You'll find such code far faster than your own. FWIW, the opening & closing quotes in “*” are ASCII 147 & 148, respectively - there's no need for the ChrW equivalents.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Did you test that though? It's not doing anything for me. I wouldn't know how to tweek the statements you're using, although I'm sure they'd be more efficient than mine.
The ChrW was chosen by the macro recorder itself. I resorted to that because I couldn't make the other alternatives work(including with Chr(147)). Couldn't even put a bloody curly quotation mark in my VBA editor, if you believe it.

Comment: Well, since I don't know what you're wanting to do with the found string, I can hardly be held responsible for "*It's not doing anything for me*" if you didn't insert the relevant code where indicated. After all, your own post and code says nothing about what reformatting is supposed to take place. And, yes, I did test it.

Comment: Like I said, I'm grateful for your suggestion, and you're certainly not responsible for anything. :) But that sub isn't doing *anything* (as in, it does not even find the string, a necessary first step). So I would need first to get it to work for me, which would require me playing around with it, and as I said I wouldn't know how.
I cannot add the formatting code in there because I want to process the string in a different sub, as I explained in the question. I'm glad to say that with the correction from @Luis Curado the whole package is working as intended now.

Comment: How do you know it's not doing *anything*? There's nothing in the code that would provide any form of feedback. Try inserting MsgBox .Text immediately after 'Do While .Find.Found'. Make sure, too, that you haven't messed up the smart quotes.